# Open server Не удалось запустить PostgreSQL-9.5

Tags: postgresql, openserver

Open server basic 5.2.6
PostgreSQL 9.5.5
В openserver/modules/database/PosrgreSQL-9.5 добавлены папки bin, lib и share из zip-архива из официального сайта PostgreSQL.
В openserver/userdata/config добавлен файл PostgreSQL-9.5.config.
Его содержимое такое же, как здесь https://gist.github.com/roderik/6843991
В настройках Open Server выбран PostgreSQL, но запустить не удается

Comment: В настройках сервера нужно включить PosrgreSQL. По умолчанию он выключен.

Comment: Да, он включен. И порт стоит 5432

Comment: https://ospanel.io/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1938 думаю здесь вы найдете ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, была на этой странице и делала все так же (добавила PostgreSQL-9.5-x64_pg_hba.conf и PostgreSQL-9.5-x64_postgresql.conf файлы) результат тот же(

Answer (score 2):

Так OpenServer basic не поддерживает Postgres + pgAdmin. Скачай премиум версию, а то у меня на домашнем компе стоит премиум и всё замечательно работает 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по умолчанию он не поддерживает, но можно добавить пользовательский модуль (что я и пытаюсь сделать), потому что мне обязательно нужна именно basic версия